# Insert data in the next row per loop in excel file using python xlwings

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xlwings

I want to automate our current process of comparing data.

Basically I want to save the data per loop and every loop it will insert the data to another row.

as of now what happening is it will just replace the data instead of inserting it to another row.

Here is my current code.

```
loadfile1 = pd.read_excel(File1)
loadfile2 = pd.read_excel(File2)

l = loadfile1.values.tolist()
m = loadfile2.values.tolist()

A = wx.Book(CompFile)

for row in l:
    if row in m:
        print('passed')
        sheet = A.sheets['Source']
        sheet.range('A1').value = row
```

Is it possible to insert the data every loop and it will just insert the data to another row

Answer (score 0):

Certainly its possible.
Your code currently writes to the same cell on each loop so it just overwrites
You can do this a couple of ways but the easiest is to simply have a row number variable that increments when a row is written.
In the example I'm assuming that `wx` is an Xlwings object. The variable 'row_number' is used as the current row to write the 'row' data to. 'row_number' is set to start at 1 (row 1) if necessary the start row can be set to another value. Then if and when a row is written to the row_number is incremented by 1 so the next write is to the next row.

```
...
A = wx.Book(CompFile)
### The Sheet object does not need to be set every time in the loop, thus 
### it can be removed from and set before the loop
sheet = A.sheets['Source']  

### Start writing from row 1 change if writing from another row
row_number = 1

for row in l:
    if row in m:
        print('passed')
        ### Use f string to create the cell co-ordinate using row_number
        sheet.range(f'A{row_number}').value = row
        row_number += 1  # Increment the row_number for the next write

A.save()  # Don't forget to save the workbook
```

Comment: This work perfectly fine thank you